# Can declval be made not to return the incorrect type for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, decltype

I have the following code and am trying to compile it in Visual Studio 2010. *I have to support a legacy customer so upgrading is not possible at the moment.*

```
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {
    static Foo CreateFoo(int p){return Foo();}
};

template <typename F, typename A0>
struct ResultOf {
    typedef decltype(boost::declval<F>()(boost::declval<A0>())) Type;
};

typedef ResultOf<decltype(&Foo::CreateFoo),int>::Type ResultType;

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!std::is_reference<ResultType>::value);
```

**The static assert fails** because a reference type is being returned rather than a value type.

I know that visual studio 2010 decltype support is sketchy. However is it possible to make the above work correctly by only modifying the decltype expression

```
typedef decltype(boost::declval<F>()(boost::declval<A0>())) ResultType;
```

I only need reliable support for functions that take one argument and return a **value** or a **reference**.

I have also noticed that if CreateFoo is a free function rather than a static method of Foo then the code compiles. They may be a work around if I can't find something better.

Comment: So what is actual problem with the given code? You mention that it is possible to make it work but I don't see any problem description. Also wouldn't it be better to use type traits from boost?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question to make it clearer. The static assert fails because decltype is incorrectly returning a reference type instead of a value. More modern compilers VS2013+ and gcc and clang all return value types and thus the static assert will not fail with them.

Comment: I remember having similiar issues in VS2010 - mostly with getting lambda's working as well. Basicly you will have a very hard time if you need to support lambda's as well. You might be better off using some library templates instead of your own. Now i don't remember off the top of my head but for instance (pseudocode)  `std::bind::result_type` or `boost::bind::result_type`

Comment: The fix so far for me is as I noted in the question. Avoid using decltype on static methods. Works fine for free functions and for lambdas but not for static methods. :)